# how to change element class when input box is disabled using angular?

Tags: angular, disabled-input

I have this input type textbox where in is it disabled and i have a separate element "button" (calendar icon) which i need to change class. is there a way in angular wherein i can overwrite or change the elements class when it sees that the input box or textbox has as property disabled?

```
<div _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" class="input-group"><input _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" angular-mydatepicker="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine" ng-reflect-name="odsdate" name="odsdate" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" disabled=""><!--container--><button _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" type="button" class="btn"><span _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" class="ftr-icon ftr-icon-leave-calendar"></span></button></div>
```

i need to create a separate class where the styles are like disabled styles
[image]

Comment: You can use a flag for both the textbox and your button. Also this method will make them dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngClass** to dynamically assign the class to change the style of the button when the textbox is disabled.

for that you have to give some pseudo name to the textbox and use that in the button to check its disability.

You can refer the below code to get the solution:

```
<div _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" class="input-group">
<input #myInput _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" angular-mydatepicker="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine" ng-reflect-name="odsdate" name="odsdate" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" disabled="">
<!--container-->
<button _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" type="button" class="btn" [ngClass="{'myClass':myInput.disabled}"]>
<span _ngcontent-nlk-c135="" class="ftr-icon ftr-icon-leave-calendar">
</span></button></div>
```